# Excel multiple if function for 70 logical test

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

i'm about to use the if function in excel 2007 for these criteria:

```
if B1 = "A" then C1 = "1"
if B1 = "B" then C1 = "2"
if B1 = "C" then C1 = "3"
if B1 = "D" then C1 = "4"
.
.
.
.
if B1 = "BP" then C1 = "68"
if B1 = "BQ" then C1 = "69"
if B1 = "BR" then C1 = "70"
```

and for the formula, this is what i usually used:

```
=IF(B1="A",C1="1",IF(B1="B",C1="2",IF(C1="C",C1="3",..and so on...)))
```

but when there have to be 70 logical tests like this, is there any other formula that is easier to use?

i hope my question is clear, and sorry if it already asked, i've tried search before asking but cant find something. thanks :)

Comment: Would you mind using a 'reference' table instead? Like having a separate table where each result is mapped from the input, and you only have to do a `vlookup` in your table to extract the data from the reference table?

Comment: yeah, i got it now :) thanks sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a lookup table on another sheet, then use the `VLOOKUP` function.  For example, enter the values A - Z in cells A1 - A26 in Sheet2 of your spreadsheet, and 1 - 26 next to those values in column B, then use the following formula in cell C1 on Sheet1:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!B1,Sheet2!A1:B26,2,FALSE)
```

(I only entered the values A - Z as an example because I didn't want to enter 70 values. You'll have to include the full range of your lookup table in place of `Sheet2!A1:B26`.)

Comment: vlookup! why cant i think of something like that! thanks sir :)

Answer (score 1):

Yea, you can just use the VLOOKUP function. It is one of the most commonly used functions in Excel currently.

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,$E$1:$F$7,2,FALSE)
```

[image: Example1]

[image: Example2]

VLOOKUP Tutorial:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd797422(v=office.12).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd797422%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Good Luck.

Comment: thanks sir, but Bill the lizard answer first :) but i really appreciate your answer

Comment: Yea, that's fine. Good luck.